# Solving Analytically 2nd order Nonlinear ODE

Tags: nonlinear-system

How to solve:

$$\displaystyle \ddot{y} + 3 y \dot{y} + y^3 - t^{-1} (y^2 + \dot{y}) - 2 t^{-2} y - 4 t^{-3} =0$$  ?

where $\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dt}$

The solution  $ y= j t^{-1}$

Comment: No there isn't.
However I have the solution y= $j t^{-1}$

Comment: Yes it is the imaginary unit.

Comment: I just tried that solution and it is not working, are you sure it is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. This is the correct equation.

Comment: Corrected version works. Actually, one also has solutions $y=-i/t$ and $y=4/t$.

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you calculate it ?

Comment: I tried $y=a/t$, which gives a cubic equation for $a$.

Comment: Is it based on a particular method?

Comment: Write the items with derivatives on the LHS and the non-derivative items on the RHS and look at the form of the RHS, then guess at a solution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Because the coefficients $-4t^{-3}, -t^{-1} and -2 t^{-2}$ in  $$  \ddot{y} + 3 y \dot{y} + y^3 - t^{-1} (y^2 + \dot{y}) - 2 t^{-2} y - 4 t^{-3} =0 $$ change depending on a given matrix.

Comment: I would be really greatful for your assistance. Thank you for the previous help.